# How to bind size change from the children class widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

If I bind the callback from the parent class, it works:

```
class rootWidget(Layout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.myWidget = myWidget()
        self.add_widget(self.myWidget)
        
        self.bind(size=self.myWidget.update_rect) # Binding here works
                                                
class myWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,1,1)
            self.rect = Rectangle()
            
        #self.parent.bind(size=self.update_rect) # Binding here does not work
            
    def update_rect(self, instance, *args):
        self.rect.size = instance.size
```

How can I bind it from the child class?
That is definitely possible since when you add a button or label, you don't bind from the parent class.

Comment: Try binding from `on_parent` method of the child widget.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm with the same problem